# incoporate reCAPTCHA using Javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, fetch-api

I am using fetch() to post data to php for further process. I don't need to have a form to accomplish the task. Here is the simplified code. Is it possible to incorporate reCAPTCHA without changing my code setup? If yes, how is it done? thanks!

```
<input type="file" name="data" id="data" ></input>
<button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="process()">Upload File</button>
```

google code

```
<script>
   function onSubmit(token) {
     document.getElementById("form_name").submit();
   }
 
<button class="g-recaptcha" 
        data-sitekey="reCAPTCHA_site_key" 
        data-callback='onSubmit' 
        data-action='submit'>Submit</button>

 </script>
```

Comment: `without changing my code setup` - sure, your button can still call `process()` - as that's the only code of yours you've shown I see no reason to change what you've shown

Answer (score 0):

**Update, option for programmatically:**

Add this div somewhere:

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha"
      data-sitekey="_your_site_key_"
      data-callback="process"
      data-size="invisible">
</div>
```

Your button:

```html
<button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="grecaptcha.execute()">Upload File</button>
```

Your button will first call `grecaptcha.execute()` and the callback will then call your `process()` function.

---

**Old Answer:**

Change your button to this:

```
<input type="file" name="data" id="data" ></input>
<button type="button" class="g-recaptcha" name="submit" id="submit" 
onclick="process()" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback='onSubmit'>Upload 
File</button>
```

Add this script snippet:

```js
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script>
  function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
  }
</script>
```

Change `demo-form` to the `id` of your form.

Here is the reference: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

Comment: i don't use form in my code as data gets posted directly to php using fetch, in which case  form becomes redundant.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it's very thorough